# Oracle SQL - How Can I Join Two Tables, One to Many?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to do a full outer join in order to get the following results. Mainly I am joining table 1 to table 2.

However in table 1, anything that has a 0 in Column A but has the same available value in Key 1 column (ABC100 Key 1 value in table 1), only use that record (record 1 in table 1), and ignore 0 record (record 2 in table 1)

When joined to table 2, specifically for ABC100, I am expecting to see output lines 1 and 2 in the expected table results.

Any help or ideas going about this?

Example:

Table 1

```
| Key 1    | Column A | 
| ABC100   | 100      |  
| ABC100   | 0        |  
| ABC300   | 200      | 
| ABC400   | 300      |
```

Table 2

```
| Key 2    | Column C | 
| ABC100   | 100      |
| ABC200   | 50       |   
| ABC300   | 200      |
```

Expected results:

```
| Key 1    | Column A | Key 2     | Column B | NVL(A,0) - NVL(B,0)
| ABC100   | 100      |  ABC100   | 100      | 0 
| ABC100   | NULL     |  NULL     | NULL     | NULL
| NULL     | NULL     |  ABC200   | 50       | -50
| ABC300   | 200      |  ABC300   | 200      | 0
| ABC400   | 300      |  NULL     | NULL     | 300
```

Comment: Why would "ABC100" appear twice in the result set if you want to ignore it?

Comment: This looks like maybe you need a full outer join.  But keep in mind that having to use a full outer join can often mean that your data model is not planned correctly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was thinking that was the possible approach. The reason I am doing this type of join is because in reality my table 1 is one accounting system and table 2 is another accounting system and the end goal is to create a reconciliation type of result set.

Answer (score 1):

Your result set suggests that you want something like this:

```
SELECT t1.key1,
       (CASE WHEN t1.a <> 0 THEN t1.a END) as a,
       (CASE WHEN t1.a <> 0 THEN t2.key2 END) as key2,
       (CASE WHEN t1.a <> 0 THEN t2.c END) as ,
       (CASE WHEN t1.a <> 0 THEN COALESCE(t1.A, 0) - COALESCE(t2.B, 0) END) as diff
FROM t1 FULL JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.Key1 = t2.Key2;
```

Your description suggests that you want:

```
SELECT t1.key1, t1.a, t2.key2, t2.c,
       COALESCE(t1.A, 0) - COALESCE(t2.B, 0) as diff
FROM (SELECT t1.*
      FROM 
      WHERE t1.A <> 0 OR
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t1 tt1 WHERE tt1.key1 = t1.key1 AND tt1.key1 <> 0)
     ) t1 FULL JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.Key1 = t2.Key2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, NVL(t1.A,0) - NVL(t2.B,0)
FROM tab1 t1
FULL JOIN tab2 t2
  ON t1.Key1=t2.Key2
```